# Request client always send method options, when send bearer token Angularjs Webapi2

Tags: c#, angularjs, rest, asp.net-web-api2, bearer-token

Hello i have made an API restful with WebAPI 2 in C#, i have enabled CORS in the api and have token authentication, and i can do almost any request to this, fo example.

I have one controller for test and have this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace ApiJSON.Controllers
{
    public class PruebaController : ApiController
    {
        // GET: api/Prueba
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET: api/Prueba/5
        [Authorize]
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST: api/Prueba
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT: api/Prueba/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE: api/Prueba/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

If i make a request from any client like Fiddler or Advance Rest Client, with the method GET to api/Prueba without token works perfect and whith api/Prueba/5 sending the bearer token it returns perfect too, but when i call from the client in angular, always send method OPTIONS and reject the promise, i tried from chrome and firefox and tried with $http, Restangular and JQuery REST Client, but always with the same result.

Thank you everyone.

**UPDATE**

Here is what the console in Chrome shows, in firefox does not show anything:

**cannot load http://localhost:49950/api/prueba/. Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.**

**UPDATE**

I have enabled CORS in the WebApiConfig.cs in this way:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.EnableCors();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            var appXmlType = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "application/xml");
            config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(appXmlType);
        }
```

And following the recommendation i added the EnableCors in the controller in this way:

```
// GET: api/Prueba/5
        [Authorize]
        [EnableCors(origins:"*", headers:"*", methods:"*")]
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }
```

I'm watching something i have in the Startup.cs, there i'm using the Microsoft.Owin.Cors in this way:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {

            app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            var myProvider = new MyAuthorizationServerProvider();
            OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions options = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
            {
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
                Provider = myProvider
            };
            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(options);
            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
            WebApiConfig.Register(config);


            //ConfigureAuth(app);
            //app.MapSignalR();
            app.Map("/signalr", map =>
            {
                map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
                var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration { };
                map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
            });


        }
```

Perhaps it is interfering with the System.Web.Http.Cors thanks again for your help.

**UPDATE**

I already find the problem, in the Global.asax i need to specified the header, this is the way i put it and work fine.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
        }
```

This is the piece of code i add:

**HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization");**

Thanks for your answers and i hope it helps someone else.

Comment: Look at the network console on your browser, it will tell you why it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your are using Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors package.

You need to actually enable CORS with either the `EnableCors` attribute on your controller (or action) or globally in the config class. The attribute seems to be missing in the code above.

This may help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it still rejecting the request.